# VBA Help to convert data in a table format to to a line format. See images for better understanding

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Sample table

[image: Sample table]

I have a 3x3 table data (3 row headers, 3 column headers with 9 table data)
I need a VBA code to display row header, column header, intersecting value from data table

The actual table is itself has a lot of rows and columns. about 145 columns and the rows constantly keep increasing in number

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your VBA code?

Comment: This can be done without VBA, using Power Query and the Unpivot command. Three clicks. Google it.

Comment: @harrymc: I have not done anything. I'm pretty new to VBA